# Angular Mocks breaking my application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-mock

I want to use `angular-mocks.js` in my application.  I have the script dependency referenced in the `<head>` and want to include it as a dependency for my module:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngMock']);
```

Before adding `ngMock` to my module, all of the AngularJS works fine.  When I include it, all of my Angular code breaks, or at least nothing generated with Angular is being displayed on the page.  For example, all I see are the expressions:

```
{{elementKey}} - {{elementValue}}
```

in my HTML, instead of the actual evaluated expressions.

No errors are being thrown in the console, so I don't know what's going wrong.  I just want to include it for unit testing purposes.

**EDIT:** I am using version 1.4.3 of angular and angular-mocks.

Comment: Are you including ngMock in your actual app or just when running your unit tests?

Comment: I am including it in my actual app.  Do I have to create a module just for running the unit tests???

Comment: Yeah, definitely don't that.  Including ngMock will cause numerous mock dependencies to be injected like `$timeout`, `$interval`, etc.  You should only be including `ngMock` as a module when running unit tests, not during your actual app

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @sma

Don't add the `ngMock` module to the application itself. Instead, just include it in the unit tests.